# Why is Google Cloud SDK (gcloud) trying to access a local MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I installed the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud) on my Windows workstation several weeks back.  I noticed that every time I run a command, I saw output similar to:

`MySQL: command not found`

... before the normal command begins.  I assumed that the SDK detected that I have MySQL installed on my workstation, and was trying (in a very buggy manner) to hook into it for Cloud SQL support.  It was annoying, but I didn't pay it much attention.

Today I ran a `gcloud components update` command, and now the SDK is altogether non-functional.  Apparently Google fixed the issue with the MySQL command's `PATH`, as the SDK **is** successfully invoking `mysql.exe` with every execution.

It's trying to connect with the MySQL user `Utilities`, and prompting me for a password.  Of course I have no idea what the password is supposed to be, since I didn't create this user.

I went into MySQL Workbench and set the password for this user to a known value, so that I can get past the password prompt triggered by the SDK.  However, the problem now is that any `gcloud` command that I type simply drops me into a MySQL shell session!

What the hell?  I'm not sure why Cloud SDK is so insistent on accessing my local MySQL environment anyway.  We do use Cloud SQL, but I have no particular interest in using `gcloud` to manage it (particularly if it's buggy).  I can't remove the Cloud SQL component from my local environment right now... because once again, any `gcloud` command simply drops me into a MySQL shell.  So I suppose my next step is to wipe the SDK off my workstation altogether, and attempt to install again without Cloud SQL selected.  Why is any of this necessary at all?

### UPDATE:

Blowing away my Cloud SDK enviroment and re-installing did not make the problem go away.  However, removing `mysql.exe` from my system `PATH` did.  Apparently, the current version of Cloud SDK simply breaks right now (at least on Windows) when it detects MySQL in your path.  I wonder how this made it past QA?

The output from `gcloud info` is below (email address and current project ID redacted):

```
> gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [0.9.67]

Platform: [Windows, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2015.06.30]
  bq-win: [2.0.18]
  core-win: [2015.06.02]
  gcloud: [2015.06.30]
  windows-ssh-tools: [2015.06.02]
  gcutil-msg: [2015.06.09]
  gsutil: [4.13]
  bq: [2.0.18]
  preview: [2015.06.30]
  gsutil-win: [4.12]
System PATH: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\sdk;C:\Program Files\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Docker\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Steve\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Groovy\GROOVY~1.3\bin;C:\Users\Steve\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5\bin;C:\Users\Steve\.dnx\bin;C:\Dev\gradle-2.4\bin;C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]

Installation Properties: [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\properties]
User Config Directory: [C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\gcloud]
User Properties: [C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\properties]
Current Workspace: [None]
Workspace Config Directory: [None]
Workspace Properties: [None]

Account: [...]
Project: [...]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [...]
    account: [...]
    disable_usage_reporting: [False]

Logs Directory: [C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs]
Last Log File: [C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2015.07.06\11.43.23.734000.log]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the question. Are you able to run 'gcloud info'? If so, can you please provide its output (deleting any private info).

Comment: @Vilas: Updated above

Comment: Thanks for the info Steve. Which commands are you noticing this behavior for?

Comment: @Vilas: Since I removed MySQL's `bin` directory from my system `PATH`, I'm not seeing the behavior at all.  However, with MySQL in the path, I see it for everything.  Just simply executing `gcloud` with no parameters sends me to a MySQL console shell.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so will post as an answer.

You probably have some environmental variable set up in a way that confuses gcloud. Can you also post the output of `set cloudsdk` from the command line? That should print all the environmental variables with the prefix "cloudsdk". You can redirect it to a file so it's easier to copy: `set cloudsdk > environment_cloudsdk.txt`.

Not sure how this can happen. If the CLOUDSDK_ env vars are empty, and gcloud.cmd is correct, gcloud shouldn't touch mysql at all. "c:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd" lists at the top what each env var does. Make sure they are not set. Also when you reinstall Cloud SDK, make sure the directory "c:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\" is properly deleted and that there's nothing in the PATH var about it.

Comment: Well yes, it's certainly an environment variable issue.  When MySQL's "bin" directory is in my system PATH, gcloud tries to run a MySQL console shell with every command.  When MySQL is not in my system PATH, gcloud does not seem to make any effort to access it.  For now, I'm working around the issue by simply removing MySQL from my PATH.  However, this seems like a bug of some kind.

Comment: BTW... when I run `set cloudsdk` right now, the only var set is one containing my Python path:  `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=C:\python27_x64\python.exe`.

Comment: Normally nobody should even try running mysql, be it path or not. Can you post the contents of "c:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd"? Something like http://pastebin.com/ should help passing the contents around.

Comment: Here you go (http://pastebin.com/3JZRvMah)... although it looks like it would require some splunking through all of the Python code, which really does all the work.

Comment: Ok, everything seems normal. I tried to repro your problem but it didn't work. If I have mysql.exe or mysql.cmd or mysql.bat anywhere in PATH, gcloud commands run just fine. My guess is the problem is not in the Python part. So let's test it out! Can you make a backup copy of "c:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py" and then replace its contents with just `print "hello"`? Now every time you call gcloud, it should only print "hello" and nothing else. Add mysql back in path. If it's still calling mysql, it's not from the python part of gcloud.

Comment: The only other thing I can see a problem with is the COMSPEC env var. Can you `set COMSPEC`? It should be `ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82756/discussion-between-valentin-and-steve-perkins).

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue, uninstall everything MySQL related, rebooted and fixed. What a mess, but my guess is that Oracle is to blame.